# How to update state after making conditional statements inside the children instance variable in a widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, conditional-statements, widget, setstate

Here, I have a `ListView.builder` that contains a list of tiles that can be incremented or decremented, which is associated with a map `itemCount` that tracks the index of each tile and records the increment for each tile.

If the counter for a tile reaches 0, it is removed and replaced with a `SizedBox.shrink()`. Once all the tiles are removed, I want the `ListView.builder` to be replaced by `Text` in the center stating 'Test Complete'. The way I have implemented this below is by using the ternary operator to check if the `itemCount` values collectively equal 0 and switch over to the `Text` stating 'Test Complete' if it does, but somehow this doesn't work.

I know that `setState` is supposed to help the app update state from `ListView.builder` to `Text` but I'm at a loss at figuring out where. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

```
import 'widgets/tiles.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Map<int, int> itemCount = {};

Future<void> main() async {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    itemCount[i] = 1;
  }
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          itemCount.values.reduce((a, b) => a + b) == 0
              ? const Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Test Complete.',
                  ),
                )
              : Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
                    25.0,
                  ),
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: itemCount.length,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Tiles(
                        index,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is `tiles.dart`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:googlebarcode/main.dart';

class Tiles extends StatefulWidget {
  final int indexValue;
  const Tiles(this.indexValue, {super.key});

  @override
  State<Tiles> createState() => _TilesState();
}

class _TilesState extends State<Tiles> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (itemCount[widget.indexValue]! > 0) {
      return Card(
        elevation: 0,
        semanticContainer: false,
        child: ListTile(
          title: Row(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.remove,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(
                    () {
                      itemCount.update(
                        widget.indexValue,
                        (value) {
                          return --value;
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
              Text(
                itemCount[widget.indexValue].toString(),
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(
                    () {
                      itemCount.update(
                        widget.indexValue,
                        (value) {
                          return ++value;
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return const SizedBox.shrink();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking `itemCount.values.reduce((a, b) => a + b) == 0` do this instead: `itemCount.isEmpty`.

**EDIT:**

```
bool? allShrunk() {
    for (var item in list) {
      if (item.runtimeType != SizedBox) return false;
      return true;
    }
  }
```

The variable `list` is just the list of children inside your column.

Comment: `itemCount` is not empty after the removal of all the tiles, it is just replaced by `SizedBox.shrink` for each tile, but the values of all `itemCount` keys become 0 when all tiles are removed. Therefore, I used that logic.

Comment: Edited my answer. It now checks if every item in side your list (`list`) is of type `SizedBox`. If so, it'll return true, else, false.

Comment: I haven't defined a variable called `list` so I don't understand your code. Even if I replace `itemCount.values.reduce((a, b) => a + b) == 0` with `allShrunk() == true` it still doesn't solve the problem of setting state while using the ternary operator.

Comment: @raptron The list is just the list of children inside your column.

Comment: Your code works, but it is equivalent to mine so it doesn't really change anything in terms of the execution of the code.